# C# using Overlapped IO even when I don't ask it to?

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming

I have a `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` that is constructed like so:

```
ClientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                          SocketType.Stream,
                          ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

Later on, I read from it in what I believe to be a synchronous manner:

```
bytesReceived = ClientSocket.Receive(aBuffer, aOffset, aSize, SocketFlags.None);
```

This will work great for many thousands of calls. Then, at some point for reasons I do not understand, I will get a SocketException with the following details:

SocketErrorCode - IOPending
ErrorCode - 996
hresult: -2147467259 (0x80004005)
Message: Overlapped I/O operation is in progress

In trying to learn more about Overlapped I/O I see it referenced mainly with async network operations. I believe I'm using a synchronous/blocking version of `Receive` so it's unclear to me why this exception would reference Overlapped IO.

Any advice? This exception happens very infrequently so gathering new data each time it happens can take days or weeks. I'm hoping there's something I'm missing or misunderstanding that can lead to a more correct approach.

As it is now, I'm working to detect this unexpected error & retry the `Receive` when this happens.

To answer some questions below:

1. All calls to `Receive` are handled on the *same* thread, but it's a different thread from the thread that created the Socket. The socket is created in the constructor and then a long running Task is spawned to repeatedly call `Receive`.
2. I don't have the sizes that were used when this failure happened.

Comment: You are not calling receive on different threads? got some more context?

Comment: Whats the size of aBuffer? and whats the value of aOffset/aSize?

Comment: Windows is multi-tasking and even if you are using a blocking method other processes are running.  The socket data is moving up and down the execution stack from application to network card asynchronous to your application code using streams.  So your synchronous read stream is still being filled by a windows process taking data from the network card and putting into the stream.

Comment: @jdweng are you suggesting that I should always be prepared to handle an Overlapped IO exception even when not using async-specific Receive calls? If so, do you have any good references/best practices for handling it? I'm not sure my "just retry the receive" is working but I haven't fully debugged that approach yet.

Comment: No I don't.  This type of exception usually occurs when you have multiple connections using same code.  I had similar issues in the past and I put a lock on common code when it was used by more than one thread.

Comment: You certainly can use different threads to access the same socket but not at the same time (concurrent sends and receives are OK). This looks like a threading bug in your code. Is that possible? Any "overlapped" stuff would be an implementation detail that's normally hidden. Indeed, all socket IO is async internally. Winsock simply blocks to give you sync IO. That's where the message likely comes from.